# How to create a db file in sqlite3 using a schema file from within python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a schema file `myschema.sql` and a database file `mydatabase.db` using `sqlite3` within python (specifically python 2.7) I would like to generate this schema in to my database.

I am aware that via the command line one can do the following

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db < myschema.sql
```

and alternatively I can do the following but this may not work on all systems:

```py
import os
os.popen("sqlite3 mydatabase.db < myschema.sql")
```

Which is not what I am after, since it may not work on some platforms.

I would also like to avoid something like:

```py
import sqlite3
schema_str = open("myschema.sql","r").read()
connection = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cur = connection.cursor()
list_of_insertions = map(lambda x: x.lstrip().replace("\n"," "),
                         schema.split(";"))
map(cur.execute, list_of_insertions)
connection.commit()
```

So parsing the file and creating the tables seperately is not what I would like either I am just looking for a python-sqlite equivalent of what can be done with the commandline tool.

Comment: What the command-line tool does is not much different from the last code.

Comment: I see so the best alternative I have to do it in a platform independant sort of manner (and within python itself) is just by parsing and executing the individual create table statements?

Comment: [`executescript`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript)?

Comment: Thats closer :D thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a helper method [`executescript`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript) exactly for that purpose:

```
with open('myschema.sql') as fp:
    cur.executescript(fp.read())  # or con.executescript
```